# JSwing make forms beautiful using net bens

Tags: java, jtable, jframe

How to make a form look more beautiful e.g the color at left is black but gradient back..how to make color of jpanel gradient black..is this an image(selected at back of jpanel)?..and similarly if i select a table how to make that table's row color black like this..

[image]

Secondly how can i make the top bar of application look like this...using jFrame..?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I would suggest reading the site's FAQ, to see how to ask questions. This is just too broad, and you don't really show any effort, nor any code

Comment: sorry for miss-convenience but i am just asking for suggetions.. i can not post my whole gui code here, i am starting to make my UI screen from start...that's why i am asking for how to make it more beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

"Make it more beautiful" is really vague and you won't get a good answer for that. You need to show us your code to help us help you.
If you just want to change how the look of your GUI in general you could just change the Look and Feel. Just add this to your code:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("<name of the look and feel>");
```

Just use Google to find something you like. [Here](http://geeknizer.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10/;) is a small collection of such Look and Feels. For further information please refer to the Java Documentation etc.

Comment: "make it more beautiful" is definitely vague. i will edit it..but i also discussed 2 scenarios if you can just guide me regarding that two scenarios that will be great..!!!

Comment: To change the background of a component you could use the setBackground( Color c )-Method. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) is the Doc for the Color-class. Just look up the methods you need in the Documentation or a tutorial or use a GUI-Builder. To make colors switch when an element is clicked, add a simple ActionListener.